# Small query with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm helping a friend with a website and need some advice. We asked here before, and were told to update all the necessary jQuery files on the server, done that, but still broken.

Website: 3six-d.co.uk

If you go to the portfolio, you will see all the pictures are out of line, not the rows, but the columns.
I'm using this to set the spacing:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <a class="fancybox-test" data-fancybox-group="thumb" href="images/portfolio-03.png"><img src="images/portfolio-preview-03.png" alt="" /></a>
</div>
```

Just to be clear I have upgraded from Bootstrap 2 to 3. But I have followed the instructions and upgraded all the syntax's. (I hope anyway) But still no luck, they just won't line up as they used to (Gaps between the columns and pictures of equal space).

I have done abit of research on this myself, and all that I can find is that they must all by in the container div, which they are.

This is driving me crazy, so I would love some help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you expect? If yes, just add following rule to your CSS

```
.fancybox-test img{
    width:100%;
}
```

[image: Columns result]

Comment: Thats what I was getting at! Thanks so much, is there a way to make the vertical padding for similar to that of the column gutters?

Comment: You could add following rule into `.col-md-4` - `padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;`. Or create an own class for this, and apply the `padding` to it.

Comment: That worked perfectly, hope Im not asking to much but could I ask you something else? I can give you a better screenshot. On firefox (not IE or Chrome) I get this line on the pictures when going through them (click on left or right) 
http://1.ii.gl/en5Jcdntl.jpg

I know its for hyperlinks and such, but if there anyway to remove it, as I think it looks pretty ugly

Comment: Add following to your CSS - `a:focus{outline:none}`

Comment: @PatrycjaSierant Please edit your `padding` to following `12px 15px 12px 15px` , so you have exact `30px` spacing.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just need to wait abit now to post again, as I have a js question too.

Comment: I feel bad for asking you this, but I checked your website and I see youre experience with js, any chance you can check this post I was about to make, http://pastebin.com/fXqsyb6p
No worried if you cant :) but thanks for all your help

Comment: I would recommend you to post it as separate question, so more people can see it. Unfortunately I'm off for today, but I'm sure somebody in another time-zone will help you! :)

Comment: Thanks anyway! Annoyingly I did post it after all, but I just got sarcastic replies about why would I even need that feature :(

Comment: I don't suppose you could take another look, I've got some help, like using an onclick clearTimeout, but with no luck

Comment: I'll take a look at your problem later today.

Comment: Thanks, I've progressed a bit further, but with no luck: http://pastebin.com/MNgyu2Sv

Answer (score 1):

You could just add the following CSS to your images.

```
.fancybox-test > img {
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The `vertical-align: middle` property removes the padding at the bottom of the images.

Answer (score 1):

Your columns are set at 31.6% width each, which is coming out at 340px wide. The preview images are 460x300 so are all overlapping. Set them a size or better yet upload the correct size.

Comment: You could also set them at 100% in the columns as others have suggested. But if you have made and are using separate files as thumbnails seams silly to then resize them.

Comment: The 31.6% was purely after experimenting with trying to fix the spacing. But thanks!

Comment: Looks like youve done it. If you want the gutters above to be equal add some padding. Bootstrap is giving them 15px padding either side currently so:
        .col-md-4 { width: 31.6%; padding: 15px 0px; }
That would add 15px padding above and below them.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <a class="thumbnail" href="images/portfolio-03.png"><img src="images/portfolio-preview-03.png" alt="" /></a>
</div>
```

What's wrong with native [`thumbnail`](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails) class of bootstrap?

Comment: I'm pretty new to Web Development and was unaware of that so thanks. The main reason though is because I want to be able to cycle through images, as that possible with Bootstrap?

Comment: What do you mean by "cycle through"? Like opening an image in a popover or something like a carousel?

Comment: Like a slideshow, to click through with similar pictures assigned the same tag.